# Starling Feathers ImageLoader error

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I am developing an app using Starling, AS3 for mobile and would like to incorporate Feathers UI. I am using Starling 1.2 and trying to add a MetalWorksMobile theme but keep getting an error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: ImageLoader

Unsure what this means or how to resolve it.

Cheers

In main .as file:

```
this._theme = new MetalWorksMobileTheme(this.stage);
```

In MetalWorksMobileTheme.as:

```
protected function imageLoaderFactory():ImageLoader
{
    const image:ImageLoader = new ImageLoader();
    image.textureScale = this.scale;
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Please post a code snippet which generates you the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the last Starling version for Feathers, you can take it here https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework.git. There isn't such error in this version.

Comment: Hi, I tried a fresh copy of Starling from the link and still the same issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it was may mistake. In this case you should update feathers too, ImageLoader was added just 7 day ago (https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/blob/master/source/feathers/controls/ImageLoader.as)